# What are some good tactical opening moves?

Tags: opening, learning, rating, tactics

I have been playing chess for about an year now. But, I am unable to get past `1300 USCF rating`. There are three phases in a chess game: opening phase, middle-game phase and end-game phase. When I get past the opening phase nicely, I usually win. But, what happens most of the time is that I get trapped in some clever openings from the opposite player and then, I try to recover from it.

Basically, I love playing tactical chess, and often get frustrated when I get caught in the tactical openings of the opposite player. So, I want to learn some good openings to improve upon my opening game for both white as well as black. A list could work or it would be best with the chess diagram illustration.

What I have learnt from experience is that: `white attacks and black defends`. Is it true? If not, how can black attack?

Comment: At 1300, I would say that studying opening theory would be a waste of valuable study time.  Have you read Logical Chess: Move by Move yet?  You should read that while playing each move (including variations on the board).  Play through all 33 games, learn the principles, and you should be able to get through the opening at minimum in roughly equal position.

Comment: As far as white attacks, black defends, there is some truth in that. There is a grandmaster who says that black has to fight just to get back to equal.  But at your level that is not true.  Players will blunder, lose tempi, otherwise waste moves, etc.  The key for black is to develop in the opening in a sound position, which will then allow you to counter attack.  And as a bonus, most of your <= 1400 Elo opponents are likely to gift you opportunities for counterplay sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 6):

What you describe is known as, "half the time when we play chess."  We simply get outplayed.  You are probably not getting caught by clever openings. You are probably making poor moves and your opponent is seizing the opportunity.

What are the ratings of your opponents who frustrate you?

White has a slight advantage at the beginning, but this advantage is really only realized at the higher levels of the game.  The reason is that amateurs waste a lot of moves so white's opening advantage goes away quickly.  Don't get too hung up on who is supposed to attack and who is supposed to defend.

Learning openings is good, but don't start memorizing a bunch of openings.  Your peers won't follow the script and you'll be as lost as they.  Instead, focus for now on opening principles.  For example, control of the center, castling, not moving the same piece twice, not bringing the queen out too early.  If you've never heard of these things, we can have a worthwhile discussion.

It's hard to give concrete advise with so few details.

One thing you can do is, after you lose, ask your opponent to review the game with you, so you can see what they were thinking.  Be prepared to do the same for your opponent when you win.

You can also ask a 1700-ish player (400 points above you) to review your game.  They will probably be able to point out issues with your play.

**edit - how to capitalize on the opening principles**

To show how the opening principles can work, there's no better example than to look at the most popular e4 opening - the Ruy Lopez.  This is a common variant.

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 b5 5. Bb3 Bc5 6. O-O
```

White and black both claim the center with the their first moves.  White's second move *develops a piece* and *attacks an unprotected black pawn*.  That's 2 good things. Black responds by developing a piece and defending the pawn.  That's good too.  White then develops a piece and attacks the Knight on c6, threatening to win the e5 pawn.  Black is unimpressed and kicks the Bishop.  In this variation, White opts to retain the Bishop and moves back.  Black kicks the Bishop again, gaining space but perhaps weakening his pawns a bit as the b-pawn will be unable to support the c-pawn.  White retires the Bishop to a pretty good square (this attacks the center, hits the weak f7, and probably Black's castled King, soon enough.)  Black then develops a Bishop.  White wastes no time in castling, which defends the chronically weak f2 square.  Every move has a purpose, almost every moves has a threat.

We see that White moved his Bishop a lot, and we're not supposed to do this, right?  The reason it is ok is that each time, there was a **purpose** to the move.  Further, White knew the Bishop could safely end up on b3, and that square looks right at the place where Black is likely to castle.

Also, don't freak out about the ratings.  They're always an approximation and very variable at that level.  You should be able to defeat a 1400-rated player about 40% of the time.

Answer (score 4):

Your description is a bit general. It's true that White tends to have more active openings as he has the first move, but it's possible to employ counter-attacking openings. As you love playing tactical openings, I would suggest adopting the [Sicilian Defense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicilian_Defence) as black - it is known to have a very distinctive active and tactical style.

Avoiding clever opening traps by your opponent is a matter of experience. When you fall for one, make sure to never fall for it again! By expanding your opening knowledge, you can enter the first stage of the game comfortably and exit it with a comfortable position.

Comment: Don't play the Sicilian without knowing the goals of the opening. Don't just memorize moves.  It doesn't help if you're stymied by `1. e4 c5 2. a3` because `a3` isn't in the books.  Your opponents won't generally play the standard moves, or know why they're playing the moves at all.  Be prepared to look at the board and swoop on their mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The question is essentially meaningless.  Tactics and moves all depend on which line and which variation of which opening happened to be done by BOTH white and black with their moves.

You need to focus on ONE opening and learn it well. You are a long way from being strong enough to want to use tactics for a quick win somehow.  Stronger players will outtactic you.

You need to learn to play a complete solid game and only use tactics when they are the correct thing to do.  Too many players want to go with slash and burn tactics when they are just starting out.

That might work against weaker players but it wont move you from 1300 to 1700, let alone 1900 or higher.

Just what are these so called tactical openings you get caught in?
Openings either tend to be open, closed, or semi open.  With early tactics more likely in the open type openings.  If you have trouble with tactics then maybe you need to move to a more closed type opening.

Better yet learn end games, pawn structure, and the rest of the techniques and info to make you a better player.

You will not go much past 1300 if all you do is tactics. And you seem to be getting beaten with that approach anyway.  So sorry, but just because you love tactics, does not make that the way to go if you want to get a higher rating.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for sharp tactical play in the opening, I like King's Gambit for that.

If you're looking to avoid nasty tactical surprise by opponents, select a few systems that are not so deep, so require less time to learn. This is a temporary fix, though. Eventually, you'd want to play main lines, like Sicilian and Ruy Lopez. But I think, in the short run there are too many lines to learn in both of these.

For example, I like Alekhine for Black after 1.e4 and Benko gambit after 1.d4. Does not work all the time but you can learn main W's surprises in a fairly short time.

Also, 1.e4 c5 2. c3 is a system I use for White in Sicilian (the most popular answer to your 1.e4, presumably). Yes it's a crutch but I just don't have time to learn the lines after 2. Nf3

You can also play 1.c4 or 1.g3 and play positional game as White. Again, to avoid nasty tactical surprises.

Answer (score 1):

I am 100% sure that kings gambit is the most tactical opening for white.
Even all E4 opening is tactical opening for white.